# Moving a number from one worksheet to another with a exception

Tags: excel-2007

I'm working on putting a gas report into Excel.

How do I have a new gas price moved to the next worksheet (day), but if there isn't a new price instead move the original price to the next worksheet?

Example:

`B6` has the gas price used in today's report (`sheet1`) and `C6` could have a new price to be used in tomorrow's report (`Sheet2`).  If `C6` has a value then I want it moved to `B6` of `Sheet2`, but if it doesn't then I want the value of `B6` in `sheet1`'s report to move to `Sheet2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try and put this into B6 of sheet2:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(sheet1!c6),sheet1!B6,sheet1!C6)
```

German version:

```
=WENN(ISTLEER(sheet1!c6);sheet1!B6;sheet1!C6)
```

Comment: @pnuts: wow, I did not know that there are differences in the formular seperators too, but your right - I adapted my answer.